# Give access to SQL staging instant in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In our GCP, we have two instances (staging and production) for SQL:

[image]

I want to give some users access to the staging instance, but not to the production instance.
This is how I try to configure this in IAM:

1. added "Cloud SQL Admin" to Roles
2. added IAM Condition "only-staging" with Name value "projects/mopla-350110/instances/staging"

See instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes?authuser=1#resource-name

[image]

[image]

[image]

But our users can still not access the "staging resource". Why is that? What did we configure wrong?

Here is the error we get when trying to navigate to the SQL tab of GCP with such a user account:

[image]

We need to do the same for the kubernetes cluster as well. Here, the instructions do not even give a resource name to add.

Comment: you need to give `roles/cloudsql.editor` role instead of Cloud SQL Admin and also Seems to be you are missing permissions `cloudsql.instances.list`. Can you grant these [roles](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-roles)  to  your respective instance and these [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-permissions) to the  users or user group whom you need to give access. Refer to this [IAM Roles Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/iam-conditions).

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: Doesnt Cloud SQL Admin also have the cloudsql.instances.list permission?

Comment: As per the [Official Doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-roles) Cloud SQL Admin don't have the `cloudsql.instances.list` permission. You need to give Cloud SQL Editor only and also When you create custom roles for Cloud SQL, make sure that if you include either `cloudsql.instances.list` or `cloudsql.instances.get`, that you include them both. Otherwise, the Google Cloud console will not function correctly for Cloud SQL.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.